# ¿cual es mi error en mi código de validación? y ¿ porque después del bucle no encuentra la información de la variable? php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

hola estaba haciendo un código con el cual hago tres validaciones primero miro si el usuario es el numero dos si lo es va a hacer lo siguiente que es primero mira su ip después de mirar su ip va a la base de datos y trae una consulta de una tabla especifica donde se encuentran las ip y después para leer la base de datos hago un bucle de `fetch_assoc()` el cual en la documentación dice lo siguiente `mysqli_fetch_assoc` - Associative array with column names as keys por lo cual al hacer el bucle valida la ip y las compara cuando son iguales almacena dentro de la variable pero cuando hago el siguiente if por fuera del bucle me dice que no existe la variable que almacena los datos que guarde ya que cuando los comparo se van a la ultima opción cual es mi error no entiendo la verdad estoy algo perdido pero porque sucede esto y cual es la solución

```
$ip = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ip_pc");
    $whatIsMyIp = include("php/ip.php");
    $ipValidaConexion = null;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($ip) > 0) {
        while ($row = $ip->fetch_assoc()) {//mysqli_fetch_assoc este metodo es para llamar los resultados de la consulta
            if ($row['ip'] == $whatIsMyIp) {
                $ipValidaConexion = $row['estado'];

            }

        }
        if ($ipValidaConexion == 'SI') {
            print "<script>alert(\"Acceso de conexion valida!\");</script>";
        } else if ($ipValidaConexion == 'NO') {
            print "<script>alert(\"Acceso desde conexion Invalida O Denegada!\");window.location='login.php';</script>";
        } else {
            print "<script>alert(\"Acceso desde conexion no registrada !\");window.location='login.php';</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "sin resultados en la DB";
    }
```

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo completo, incluyendo el `php/ip.php`. Saludos

Comment: podria mostrar el error que se produce

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: @Ruben es simplemente el código que trae la ip como cuando le preguntas a Google cual es mi ip hace la misma acción y se que es funcional tranquilo pero te dejo la documentación de donde lo copie https://ejemplocodigo.com/ejemplo-php-obtener-la-ip-real-de-una-visita/ es básicamente lo mismo

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez solo como dije cuando guardo los datos de la base de datos en la variable        ``` while ($row = $ip->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row['ip'] == $whatIsMyIp) {
                $ipValidaConexion = $row['estado'];

            } ``` y en siguiente if la llamo ya no hay nada ``` if ($ipValidaConexion == 'SI') ```   por lo cual al parecer llega vacío porque si dejo esa variable de evaluación en ves de un ```'SI'``` un ```''``` de dato de texto vacío hay si se cumple el if

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo una mal ejecución del codigo
esto no va a funcionar
`$whatIsMyIp = include("php/ip.php");`

tienes que hacer lo siguiente

```
include("php/ip.php");
$ip = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ip_pc");
$whatIsMyIp = getRealIP(); //asumiendo que estas utilizando el codigo que me comentaste en en los comentarios
$ipValidaConexion = null;
.....
```

Comment: ok lo voy a probar

Comment: funciona asta cierto punto solo puedo haceder desde la primera ip pero cuando intento acceder con la segunda ip que se encuentra en la base de datos me bota error y ya me asegure de que fueran iguales

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias

Comment: @JuanFelipeCorreaRíos marcarlo como la respuesta correcta o votar como positiva ayudaria mucho!, saludos.